# com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: no web.xml present

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, jsf, web.xml

I programmed an application with JSF and some other fraeworks. Then I destroyed my metadata with maven and then I created a new project and imported all my classes and config files into the new project. So that I have clean metadata. The Project can be built without problems now. But when I want to start it onto tomcat I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: no web.xml present
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.scanForFacesServlet(ConfigureListener.java:785)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.<init>(ConfigureListener.java:745)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

But there is definitely a `web.xml` in that project. Has somebody an idea where my mistake could be? Thank you

---

### Update

- Yes I am using m2Eclipse!
- My directory tree looks like:

*OLD*

My Servlet is there as well:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

---

### UPDATE2

- Directories (after BalusC Commend):
  [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/) I have found a good Manual about Maven Web Projects. But unfortunately the problem stayed the same. 
  My directory structure looks like:
  [image]

---

### UPDATE3

Response to Pascal's comment:

- `mvn clean compile` is successfull
- `mvn install` throws a build error:

  `[INFO] Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if execut ing in update mode)`

I executed those commands from windows console

---

Maybe the problem is something else. There is another Warning while starting the server:

```
27.08.2010 09:04:52 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:studentportal' did not find a matching property.
```

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Do you use eclipse and m2eclipse plugin ?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your project (the output of `tree`, without `target`)?

Comment: Is the problem reproducible? After a `mvn clean compile`? Sometimes m2eclipse doesn't copy resources as expected (which is pretty annoying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started a new project and moved one part at once. After that it works. Unfortunately I have no idea where the problem was -.-

But creating a new empty project and moving all the files (except config files, I wrote them again) is a reasonable approach..

Answer (score 3):

Some pointers. Is the web.xml placed at WEB-INF/web.xml ?

From the source code, this particular exception is thrown at:

```
InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream(WEB_XML_PATH);
            if (in == null) {
                if (context.getMajorVersion() < 3) {
                    throw new ConfigurationException("no web.xml present");
                }
            }
```

and it's looking for web.xml at

```
private static final String WEB_XML_PATH = "/WEB-INF/web.xml";
```

So it did not find the web.xml.

Also for some reason it's expecting Servlet 3.0 which is only available with Tomcat 7.0 - but I think the main issue should be the presence of web.xml

Finally, it will also be looking for the defined servlet in the web.xml like below

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```